# how can I redirect to login when using SSOfy as authentication SDK in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on

We recently decided to use the SSOfy authentication server and successfully installed both the client and server SDKs. Now I must implement a redirection to the login page in a Laravel service class when the user is not authenticated. I'm not sure if I should use Laravel's "old redirect to login page" route or if I should redirect to a specific route.

I have a function in my service class that checks whether the user is authenticated or not. I need to redirect the user to the SSOfy login page if they are not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the "ssofy:redirect" middleware within a single route or group to achieve the desired functionality, and it will handle the redirect for you seamlessly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).